Regularity of continuous approximation on time discretization
I have been trying to understand how to deal with continuous approximations when dealing with time discretizations, consider the abstract PDE
$$
\partial_t u + A(u) = f(u)
$$
and then instead splitting the time domain into intervals instead we work with
$$
\delta_t u^i + A(u^i) = f(u^i)
$$
where $\delta_t u^i = (u^i - u^{i-1})/k$, where $k$ is our timestep, this now becomes an elliptic problem and once existence is shown we would like to go back to the continuous case.
Temam works with such abstraction in his N-S theory and Numerical Analysis book, now the idea presented to go back to the continuous case is by setting the step function
$$
u_k(t) = u^i \ \text{for } t\in \left[(i-1)k , ik \right)
$$
and the linear by parts $w_k(t)$ which can be set for instance as
$$
w_k(t) = u^i + \frac{t-ki}{k}\left( u^i  - u^{i-1} \right)
$$
Now my question is the following, in Temam's book he has that $u_0 \in L^2$, and he can prove that
$$
 k \sum_{i=1}^N \| \nabla u^i \|^2  \leq C, \quad  |u^i|^2 \leq C
$$
that is, $u^i\in H^1$ for every subsequent $i$ (as expected in the regularizing effect of the PDE), but in Lemma 4.7 he states that $w_k \in L^2(0,T,H^1)$, but in this case I don't know how to deal with the first interval, that is, the fact that $u^o \notin H^1$, but am instead able to see that $w_k \in L^2(k,T,H^1)$, so what am I missing here?

I think that the problem does not arise, since if $w_k \in L^2(0,T,H^1)$, it means that $w_k(t) \in H^1$ for a.e. $t \in [0,T]$, so even if $u^0 \notin H^1$ we do not care

@LucioRosi my issue is precisely with the first interval $(0,k)$ which has a measure, otherwise we are discussing the limit of a changing domain alongside the limit of a function later on

I think you need to assume first that $u_0\in H^1$. In this case, you can apply Temam’s proof.
When $u_0\in L^2$, construct a sequence $u_{0,n}\in H^1$ such that $u_{0,n}\to u_0$ in $L^2$. Let $u_n$ be the solution with initial value $u_{0,n}$. You can show that $u_n$ converges to a solution $u$ with initial value $u_0$. The details are here.pde see Theorems 66 and 68.

That was my initial thought as well, just wasn't sure as it wasn't very explicit explained
